# 404 error: Page not found in Magento while running cron jobs parallely

Tags: php, magento, cron, http-status-code-404

I am getting "404 error: Page not found" in Magento. But, if I refresh page, I am getting corresponding page. And If I click on products or links in page, Once again getting "404 error: Page not found" and If I refresh, I am getting corresponding Page.  Can any one help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked file / folder permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check any change in the urls when you made a click on the link and when you made a refresh of the page? Is there any difference in their url's???

Comment: Welcome to SO! One thing, though, this could be a comment instead of a answer.

Comment: Yes i checked. There is no difference in Url's before and after refresh.

Comment: I observed that i am getting "404 error: Page not found" while cron jobs are running. Please help me.